# errores en mis metodos de java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion para trabajar polinomios pero tengi algunos errores en las funciones que defino y no se como arreglarlos por eso les pido ayuda

Un método void al que se le pasa por parámetro un entero que indica la posición de un coeficiente del polinomio y otro entero, que representa un valor. El método establece el coeficiente del polinomio en esa posicion al valor del segundo argumento

Una ultima funcion en la que se le pasa un parámetro que representa un float llamado y devuelve otro float del polinomio para la incognita x = valorSustitucion donde valorSustitucion es valor pasado como parámetro a la funcion.

```
public class AppPolinomio { 
    private int[] polinomio;    
                
    public AppPolinomio(int[] array) {
//El primer elemento del vector representa el término independiente, el segundo el coeficiente del término de grado 1...
         this.polinomio = array;
   }
            
    public void estabCoef(int posicion, int value) { // Debe establecer el coef en la posicion a value
        int valor = polinomio[posicion];
        valor = value;
    }
}
```

Espero puedann ayudarme y gracias!!

Comment: Ayudaría mucho si explicaras paso  paso lo que se debe hacer en cada función. Empezando con el constructor que recibe un arreglo de enteros ... qué se debe hacer luego con ese arreglo? Luego explica el segundo método agrega ejemplos de qué debe hacer, cómo lo debe hacer y qué resultados se esperan y lo mismo con el tercer método.

Comment: Para empezar, si la clase se llama `AppPolinomio`, el constructor de esa clase se tiene que llamar `AppPolinomio` y no `Polinomio`. Siguiendo con el constructor, defines una variable `terminoi` que no sirve para nada porque es local a la función y al salir de la función se destruye y se pierde. Y luego haces `new` de enteros usando la variable `grado` que no has inicializado... La función `estabCoef` no hace nada de nada. Lo que hace no afecta en nada al objeto... `tamañoGrado` lo mismo: usa `grado` que no estableces nunca. En fin, que hay demasiados errores para que algo tenga sentido.

Comment: No, la variable `grado` la creas al principio pero no le das valor en ningún momento, y es privada, así que esa variable se quedará con el valor por defecto que ponga el compilador para un entero, que que será `0`. Y la función `estabCoef` sigue sin tener sentido: Creas una variable de nombre `valor`, le asignas lo que tenga `polinomio[posicion]`, pero luego ese valor lo pierdes porque a `valor` le asignas lo que se recibe como parámetro en `value`. De todas formas da igual porque todo se pierde al salir de la función, ya que `valor` es una variable local a la función y no miembro de la clase.

Comment: Desisto, no te entiendo. No se qué pretendes conseguir pero no se entiende. Te recomiendo volver a empezar con java y que aprendas lo que es una clase, un objeto, una variable, el ámbito de las variables. Lo básico. Porque parece que no lo has entendido. Dime un solo sitio donde tu variable grado cambie de valor en tu programa. Uno solo. Si no cambia nunca. Para qué haces if para comprobar el valor de grado si no hay un solo sitio en tu código donde cambie de valor. Siempre va a valer 0.